# BeautifulSoup misses specific <div> zippy elements

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse Google support pages, and the parsed soup does not include the zippy  elements.

Example: on this [page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6286986?hl=en) we have the following zippy elements:

```
<div class="zippy-container"><a class="zippy index1 goog-zippy-expanded" data-sc-zippy-id="play-store-app" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" role="button" data-stats-ve="2" data-stats-imp="" data-stats-idx="1,17" data-stats-ignore="" data-outlined="false">Play Store app</a></div>
<div class="zippy-overflow"><div class="zippy-content" style="margin-top: 0px; transition: margin-top 0.218s ease-out 0s; overflow: auto;"><ol>
  <li>Open the Google Play app <img src="//storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/HIW81g8nflvhNKmYm3Q1IYhcWa6h9CBASKWd" width="18" height="18" alt="Google Play" data-mime-type="image/png">.</li>
  <li>At the top right, tap the profile icon.</li>
  <li>Tap <strong>Settings</strong> <img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/3_l97rr0GvhSP2XV5OoCkV2ZDTIisAOczrSdzNCBxhIKWrjXjHucxNwocghoUa39gw=w36-h36" width="18" height="18" alt="and then" data-mime-type="image/png" data-alt-src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/3_l97rr0GvhSP2XV5OoCkV2ZDTIisAOczrSdzNCBxhIKWrjXjHucxNwocghoUa39gw"> <strong>Family </strong><img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/3_l97rr0GvhSP2XV5OoCkV2ZDTIisAOczrSdzNCBxhIKWrjXjHucxNwocghoUa39gw=w36-h36" width="18" height="18" alt="and then" data-mime-type="image/png" data-alt-src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/3_l97rr0GvhSP2XV5OoCkV2ZDTIisAOczrSdzNCBxhIKWrjXjHucxNwocghoUa39gw"> <strong>Manage family members</strong>.</li>
  <li>Tap <strong>Invite family members</strong> <img src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/3_l97rr0GvhSP2XV5OoCkV2ZDTIisAOczrSdzNCBxhIKWrjXjHucxNwocghoUa39gw=w36-h36" width="18" height="18" alt="and then" data-mime-type="image/png" data-alt-src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/3_l97rr0GvhSP2XV5OoCkV2ZDTIisAOczrSdzNCBxhIKWrjXjHucxNwocghoUa39gw"> <strong>Send</strong>.</li>
</ol>
</div></div>
```

I run:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(document_source, features='html.parser')
```

These elements are not in the parsed soup, but are "stripped" from the divs that contained them.

[image: Parsed zippy elements]

I tried using html5lib as well, but it did not help in this case.
Would be great to get help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The page adds CSS classes to tags dynamically, so you have to select tags with other methods (for example using `.find_next_sibling`):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6286986?hl=en"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for zippy in soup.select('.zippy'):
    print(zippy.text)
    print('-' * 120)
    div = zippy.find_next_sibling('div')
    print(div.get_text().strip())
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Play Store app
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open the Google Play app .
At the top right, tap the profile icon.
Tap Settings  Family  Manage family members.
Tap Invite family members  Send.

Family Link app
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Important: Family Link availability may be limited in some countries. Download the Family Link app.

On your Android phone or tablet, open Family Link .
At the top left, tap Menu   Manage family  Send invitations.

Google One app
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Anyone in a family group can purchase a Google One membership and share it with their whole family, up to 6 members total, at no extra cost.

On your Android phone or tablet, open the Google One app .
At the top, tap Menu  Settings.
Tap Manage family settings.
Turn on Share Google One with your family. To confirm, on the next screen, tap Share.
Tap Manage family group  Invite family members.
Follow the instructions to finish setup.

...and so on.
```

Comment: Hi Andrej! is there a way to reach you regarding specific issue am facing ? need your help

Comment: Thanks Andrej!

This is a good way of doing it, but I'm not sure I understand how the entire divs disappeared (e.g. the 'zippy-container').
Is there something dynamic in the generation of those divs?

As you can tell, I'm not a FE expert, so apologies if this is basic stuff